# removing element from complicated array

Tags: jquery

I know that with using grep I can remove an item from array

```
var y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4]
var removeItem = 2;

alert('Array before removing the element = '+y);
y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
 return value != removeItem;
  });
    alert('Array after removing the element = '+y);
```

but if I have an array like this :

```
 var typesHash=[
                 {id:'1', name : 'lemon', price : 100,unit:2.5 },       
                 {id:'2', name : 'meat', price : 200,unit:3.3  }];
```

How can I remove item with id:'1' but without looping through the array ? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value.id` instead of `value` in your `grep` function:

```
jQuery.grep(typesHash, function(value) {
    return value.id != removeItem;
});
```